# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: scala/collection/Seq : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, scala

I have two applications one is written in Java and the other is written in Scala.

The java application is using the Scala application as a library. When I build the java application against JDK 1.8 every thing works fine.

When I build the application against JDK 1.7, the application throw the following exception.

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: scala/collection/Seq :
>   Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

It seems that the Scala application is only compatible with JDK 1.8.

I tried to change the project compiler settings in the Scala project and set the target JVM into version 1.7 but nothing changed.

Any suggestions to have the application run against JDK 1.7 ?

Comment: is you have sources compiled with any JDK 1.8.x, you won't be able to run them with a JDK 1.7.x

Comment: @FranMontero I have the source code of the Scala application. How could I have it compiled against 1.7?

Comment: I do not know about scala but Java. If you achieve to compile the Scala app using a 1.7 JDK  your problem will be gone ;)

Comment: Add this key to your build: ```scalacOptions := Seq("-target:jvm-1.7")```

Comment: If you are you scala libs based on Java8, like Play since version 2.4, you also need to compile your own app in 1.8.